# How C++ boost::filesystem detect if path is file or directory?

Tags: c++, boost

In boost::filesystem library is there any way to determine if the path is directory or file?

My scenario is : I have some folders and files which i need full path of the all files and push it to vector, so i did this :

```
for ( boost::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator end, dir(pathBase);
    dir != end; ++dir ) {
    if ( boost::filesystem::exists( dir->path() ) )
    {
        std::cout << dir->path() << "\n";  // full path
        filenames.push_back(dir->path().string());
    }
  }
```

The problem is the `exists` method check if directory or file exist and could not detect their type(file or directory).

So how can i get only files with boost library?

Comment: Read the manual? http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like you need [`boost::filesystem::is_regular_file`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#is_regular_file2).

Comment: Thanks , I've searched for is_file but apparently it don't exist in library.

Comment: Ever heard of the `!` operator?

Comment: @tambre: Unfortunately, it's not that easy (inverting the result of `is_directory`). There are paths which are neither directories nor regular files, for example `.` and `..`.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: I'm pretty sure `.` and `..` are directories. `C:` on the other hand isn't. And linux can have pipes in the file system.